# How to change custom view size dynamically while drawing it on canvas?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-view

I want to draw a callout type view (LinearLayout in this case) where callout background is the a CardView and title is the TextView. How do I change the size of the layout based on the size of the text. I've tried wrap content but it's not working.

**layout_callout_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_2dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white">
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/markerCalloutTitle"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:textColor="#010202"
      android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16sp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:gravity="center">
  </TextView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_6dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/tips_location_marker_callout_pointer"/>
```

Assuming **calloutView** as object

```
onDraw{
---
---
calloutView.draw(canvas,x,y,paint)
}
```

Comment: Are u looking for a custom view like a truecaller? But Your custom view has to expand his height based on the text.Am I right?

Comment: I don't about truecaller but I have an image and couple of points on that image. If a user clicks on any particular point it will popup a rectangle shape callout and will display the text